# Remove local repo from Github

Tags: git, github

I am new to Github so this question may seem very basic. I tried to upload contents of a folder to a Github repo using this link: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line.

Later I want to do the same thing for a parent of the first folder, but I cannot access the content of the first folder on Github anymore. There is a warning

```
You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
```

I am trying to undo the first step so that I can do the second step.

Comment: There's a folder called `.git` inside the inner folder. You might not be able to see it but it's there. You can delete it like any other folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first folder will contain a folder `.git` which might be hidden. That `.git` folder contains all the repository information about the first folder including revision history, config, metadata, etc. If you don't need it anymore, you can simply delete it, then commit in the parent repository and push.